# Error when calculating cos (x) and sin (x) with opencv

Tags: c++, matlab, qt, opencv, trigonometry

I don't know why the sin() and cos() of a double which suppose to have a certain value it gives me wrong value when I debug using Qt

here is my code :

```
Vec3d nor2 ( 0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0);
double jphi = 0.0 ;
double phi2 = 0.0 ;

 for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++)
        {
            double jphi = (i+1) * step_phi - phimax ;

           double phi2 = phi_0 + CV_PI * jphi / 180.0 ;

            // apply partial phi-rotation in (x-z) plane
            nor2 = (cos(phi2), 0.0 , sin(phi2));

}
```

the value of `nor2 = (0.620691455366943 , 0 , 0)`for the first iteration
when I did it with matlab it gives me `nor2 = (0.7841 , 0 , 0.6207)`

Comment: What is the value of `phi2`?

Comment: the value of phi2 is 0.669624292283149

Comment: The value of `(cos(phi2), 0.0 , sin(phi2))` is `sin(phi2)`. If you want a vector of three coordinates, write `Vec3d(cos(phi2), 0.0 , sin(phi2))`

Comment: @molbdnilo what do you mean ?

Comment: @ner The comma operator evaluates the left-hand side, discards the result, and returns the value of the right-hand side. That is, the value of `1,2` is `2`. Adding parentheses does nothing.

Comment: @molbdnilo what do you suggest i do, i m really lost

Comment: @ner I converted my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the expected result, but not in the expected place - `0.6207` is `0.620691455366943` rounded to four decimal places.

The problem is that you're using the comma operator, which evaluates the left-hand side, discards the result, and returns the value of the right-hand side.
That is, the value of `(cos(phi2), 0.0 , sin(phi2))` is `sin(phi2)` (the parentheses don't change this).

You need to do this:

```
nor2 = Vec3d(cos(phi2), 0.0 , sin(phi2));
```

Comment: thank you @molbdnilo this fixes my problem and return the write values